# vim and NERD Tree: Can NERD Tree persist across tabs in MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

When using NERD Tree on MacVim, I can open a file in a new tab by using 't' (or 'T' to open it in the background) in the NERD Tree window, but when I switch to that tab, the NERD Tree window is no longer visible since it remains in the original tab.  Is there a way to automatically open NERD Tree in new tabs when opening files from NERD Tree in new tabs?  Or can NERD Tree persist across tabs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use `:NERDTreeMirror`. I prefer this to NERDTreeToggle when at least one tree is already open because it keeps the tree consistent across tabs.

Answer (score 57):

This NERDTree behavior was a pain for me, too. It annoyed me so much that I learned VimScript and made a plugin that keeps NERDTree consistent across all tabs all the time.

You can grab it on Github: https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs

Comment: This is wonderful. Definitely what I and and the original author was looking for; should be the official answer since this doesn't require anymore key strokes from the user once set up.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, thank you.  Your plugin makes NERDTree useful.  I use it all day every day.

Comment: Thanks everyone for letting me know you like the plugin, it makes me feel happy :)

Answer (score 5):

The only persistent object in Vim is a buffer.  Windows display buffers, tab pages organize windows.  If you want to open NERD Tree in the new tab, then call `:NERDTreeToggle`.  Another option would be to open a new tab, open NERD Tree, and then open the file in your freshly created tab.

I wonder, though, why you would want to have a file tree open all the time.  It's just a waste of space, most of the time.  You can map a key to call `:NERDTreeToggle` to easily make it visible when you actually need to use it.